# How do i add status column in product grid section in manage category in magento?

Tags: php, magento

How can i add status column in product grid in manage categories section? I want to add status column next to SKU.

Catalog / Manage Categories / select any category and you can able to see the mapped products under "category products". There i want to add status column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can write a backend extension which does that.

Comment: ok thanks for your idea. So i have to override that block?

Comment: I have overridden the block. And it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy this file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Product.php` to your local folder or directly in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Product.php`

Line 79, just before `->addAttributeToSelect('price'),`

add this code: `->addAttributeToSelect('status')`

Line 128, just before `$this->addColumn('price', array(,` add this code:

```
$this->addColumn('status',
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Status'),
                    'width' => '70px',
                    'index' => 'status',
                    'type'  => 'options',
                    'options' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getOptionArray(),
            ));
```

Run Compilation again if it is enabled. Refresh your page, you'll see "Status" column next to the SKU column